# JPA/Hibernate: is it obvious to create UserType when using AttributeConverter on complex class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'd like to map an arbitrary POJO class attribute as a `String` with an `AttributeConverter<SomeClass, String>` but I get this:

> WARN: Could not find matching type descriptor for requested Java class [SomeClass]; using fallback

Does that mean `AttributeConverter` is not enough and I need to write a custom `UserType` for every complex class to be able transforming it into `String` and back?

[Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419328/hibernate-using-complex-classes-as-properties) requires `@Embeddable`. Is it more suitable here?

```
@Entity
public class SomePersistentClass {
    @Id
    int id;

    @Convert(converter = SomeClassConverter.class)
    public SomeClass attribute;

    //...
}

public class SomeClass {
    //...
}
```

Comment: It's enough with other JPA implementations (e.g DataNucleus), since an AttributeConverter is an instruction to say "persist as this supported type". If Hibernate requires that, then you would be within your rights to raise an issue on them

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but as of Hibernate 5.2.7 (Jan 24th, 2017) this warning changed to:

> WARN org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry -
>   HHH000481: Encountered Java type [class SomeClass] for which we could
>   not locate a JavaTypeDescriptor and which does not appear to implement
>   equals and/or hashCode. This can lead to significant performance
>   problems when performing equality/dirty checking involving this Java
>   type. Consider registering a custom JavaTypeDescriptor or at least
>   implementing equals/hashCode. So, there are these solutions:

To solve this, simply make sure your type implements equals and hashcode, and also annotate it with Immutable.class in case it is immutable.

See: [JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry - Could not find matching type descriptor for requested Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795355/javatypedescriptorregistry-could-not-find-matching-type-descriptor-for-request)

Answer (score 0):

Define the pojo with

1. **@Named**
2. implements **Converter**
3. Override the getAsObject and getAsString method

Comment: What is `@Named?` Hibernate and JPA do not have this annotation. Could you give an example please?

Comment: @Named should be the standard for JavaEE6 , which is related to CDI,

Comment: and if the user isn't using JavaEE or CDI ?!

Comment: oh i see, we are talking about different aspect of convert , yours should be related to this one : http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/